# Events abc independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If the events a, b is independent,  a c is independent, do you think (a, bc) is also independent?

---

Attemp:

P(A, BC) is independent if P(A, BC) = P(A) P(BC). But is this same as P(ABC)?

Comment: $\{\,100,010,001,111\,\}$. 1st digit one is independent of 2nd digit one; 1st digit one is independent of 3rd digit one; 1st digit one is not independent of (2nd digit one and 3rd digit one).

Comment: @GerryMyerson, What is your example. Do you mind to maybe elaborate a bit in details please?

Comment: Your question has been closed as a duplicate. Have you looked to see whether the earlier question resolves the problem?

Comment: Yes, I only see that question, people are arguing.

Comment: In my example, we have four outcomes, equally likely. $A$ is the event, "1st digit is one," so $A=\{\,100,111\,\}$.  $B$ is "2nd digit is one," $C$ is "3rd digit is one." $P(A)=P(A|B)=1/2$, $P(A)=P(A|C)=1/2$, but $P(A|BC)=1$.

Comment: I c. Thanks for the comment. I got it now.